# Why is my weight painting not working properly?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

I started working on the rig today and it worked fine until just about half an hour ago (when I deleted/dissolved the bones from the centre of the hand to the base of each finger). Now the weight paint for the base of each finger bone doesn't act properly. Please advise.
[image: before deforming the bone]

[image: after deforming the bone]

Comment: if the vertices that are moving unintentionally are only part of the finger vertex group and no other one, they will be moved as if they were 100% part of the finger group, even if their weight is 0.01. So what you may need to to is also assign these vertices to the palm vertex group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assigned your mesh object to the armature, you might have used automatic weights(which is super helpful). When you use that, on the mesh it creates a vertex group for each bone in the armature (each group is named the same as the bone). When you weight paint, you're modifying the values of those vertex groups.

When you deleted a bone, I'm assuming the vertex group was not deleted with it. So now part of your mesh has a vertex group named after that bone and this new bone might have a new name but not a new vertex group associated with it. Look over your vertex groups and make sure they all reference your current armature bone names.

To help troubleshoot this, with the armature selected in Object Data Properties > Viewport Display, check show "Names". Each bone will show its name, then you can select the mesh and check all the vertex groups and makes sure they sync with your bones.

[image]
[image]

Comment: After a bit of troubleshooting, this does seem to be the case! I have two sets of vertex groups in the Vertex groups panel. One set made along with the automatic weights and another set I named after I deleted the bone. Even after I deleted one set of vertex groups there's more bugs popping up(Like the whole mesh showing up purple when selected and then resetting back again after I painted it separately; and others...). I think I will need to start with a fresh armature without deleting the bones. 

Either way, thanks for your help with the troubleshooting!

Comment: @Praneeth, glad it worked for you! Good luck with the rest of your project. If the answer worked, please mark it as accepted. Have a great day!